# What is the difference between msdeploy and web deploy?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, webdeploy

It looks like web deploy is just a different way of calling msdeploy. I've read some documentation but still don't understand the difference between the two.

It's still referred to as the "Web Deploy tool" but I don't understand what distinguishes it from msdeploy.exe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft Web Deploy is the official name, while msdeploy is the name of the executable.

You can download and install Web Deploy from a place such as Microsoft Downloads,

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

And then you can use `msdeploy` command, as it is installed to

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"

So in a simple way, the two are the same thing.

Comment: oh I guess that makes sense. but I can use mdeploy without web deploy right? I guess that what im confused about. Can't you even install msdeploy without web deploy? there isn't a web deploy command line tool so how does web deploy use msdeploy?

Comment: Updated the answer with more details.